# Android - How to export dependency tree to a file?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.1.0

I want to export the dependency tree to a file. How can I do so?

Below is the command I used to generate dependency

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies > ~/Desktop/output.txt
```